# What is the benefit of passing state as function parameter?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I wonder if there is any benefit to getting the current value of a MutableStateFlow and passing it as an argument to a function to update it as follows:

```
class OrderViewModel : ViewModel() {
    fun updateSideDish(sideDish: SideDishItem) {
        val previousSideDish = _uiState.value.sideDish // <-- storing state
        updateItem(sideDish, previousSideDish)         // <-- passing as argument
    }

     private fun updateItem(newItem: MenuItem, previousItem: MenuItem?) {
            _uiState.update { currentState ->
                val previousItemPrice = previousItem?.price ?: 0.0
                // subtract previous item price in case an item of this category was already added.
                val itemTotalPrice = currentState.itemTotalPrice - previousItemPrice + newItem.price
                // recalculate tax
                val tax = itemTotalPrice * taxRate
                currentState.copy(
                    itemTotalPrice = itemTotalPrice,
                    orderTax = tax,
                    orderTotalPrice = itemTotalPrice + tax,
                    entree = if (newItem is EntreeItem) newItem else currentState.entree,
                    sideDish = if (newItem is SideDishItem) newItem else currentState.sideDish,
                    accompaniment =
                    if (newItem is AccompanimentItem) newItem else currentState.accompaniment
                )
            }
        }
}
```

Rather than just passing the new changes without the previous parameter as follows:

```
class OrderViewModel : ViewModel() {
    fun updateSideDish(sideDish: SideDishItem) {
        updateItem(sideDish) // <-- no more argument   
    }

     private fun updateItem(newItem: MenuItem) {
            _uiState.update { currentState ->
                val previousItemPrice = when (newItem) {      // <-- calculate previous item here
                    is EntreeItem -> currentState.entree?.price ?: 0.0
                    is SideDishItem -> currentState.sideDish?.price ?: 0.0
                    is AccompanimentItem -> currentState.accompaniment?.price ?: 0.0
                }
                // subtract previous item price in case an item of this category was already added.
                val itemTotalPrice = currentState.itemTotalPrice - previousItemPrice + newItem.price
                // recalculate tax
                val tax = itemTotalPrice * taxRate
                currentState.copy(
                    itemTotalPrice = itemTotalPrice,
                    orderTax = tax,
                    orderTotalPrice = itemTotalPrice + tax,
                    entree = if (newItem is EntreeItem) newItem else currentState.entree,
                    sideDish = if (newItem is SideDishItem) newItem else currentState.sideDish,
                    accompaniment =
                    if (newItem is AccompanimentItem) newItem else currentState.accompaniment
                )
            }
        }
}
```

Since the first code is part of this Google [codelab](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-compose-navigation), I want to know if there is any benefit except the readability.

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely use the second variant.

The previous item is integral to the calculations you do, and the only reliable source of that is the flow's `update` lambda.

Let's just compare the previous item in both variants:

```
val previousSideDish = _uiState.value.sideDish

_uiState.update { currentState ->
    val alwaysTrue = currentState.sideDish == previousSideDish // wrong!
}
```

You might assume `alwaysTrue` is... well, always true. After all, you retrieve the current flow's value twice directly without anything in between. This isn't the case, though, since the flow is asynchronous in nature and could have been updated in between these two calls from somewhere else. And in that case `alwaysTrue` will be `false`.

Only the `update` lambda of the flow is guaranteed to be executed atomically with nothing else being able to interfere with the flow while it is running.
If you need the previous value of the flow to calculate its new value, you have to put all of that inside of the `update` lambda.